# What will be the designer surface for the razor view engine?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-3

Razor looks like a winner for developers...close to the metal, yet quick and efficient.

As a developer who is not good with a designer's stylus pen, at some point I want to pass my ham-handed design to a professional designer. What will be the design surface that such a designer will use?  Will Expression Web be enabled with a knowledge of razor syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a designer that has full support for Razor Syntax at the moment :(.

I'd hope MS would add support for it. But I've not seen anything yeah or nay from them as of yet.

Guess we'll have to wait until the next update from them... keep following scottgu ;)